# Is there any other way to build pipe in C?

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe, system-calls

I want to know that is this possible to code this program with using `write()`, `read()` functions. It takes 2 initial arguments with `argv[]` then `fork()` and after that child process' stdout passes to parents stdin and result will be showed on screen.

when I execute the program like this ---> `./program date wc`

It must show a result as same as `date | wc` does in shell programming.

I coded this program with `dup()`. it works fine but I want to other way around. Thank you and sorry for my english.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


char* argument1[]={argv[1], NULL};
char* argument2[]={argv[2], NULL};
int fd[2];
int d;
pid_t pid;
char buffer[30];

if(argc < 3){
printf("No parameter");
return 1;
}

if(pipe(fd)==-1){
perror("pipe failed");
exit(1);
}

else{

   pid=fork();

   if(pid==0){
   /*child process*/
   close(1);
   dup(fd[1]);
   close(fd[0]);

   //close(fd[1]);

   execvp(argument1[0], argument1);

   }

   else if(pid>0){
   /*Parent process*/
   close(0);
   dup(fd[0]);
   close(fd[1]);

   //close(fd[0]);

   execvp(argument2[0], argument2);


   }

}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm not clear quite what your problem is or what you're after.  You should have `close(fd[1]);` in your child process code, and `close(fd[0]);` in your parent process code.  You should also report an error and exit after each `execvp()`, just in case something goes wrong.  You don't have to test the return value from `execvp()`; it only returns if there is an error.  Other than those issues (which are fairly minor in this context, though they could be problematic in bigger contexts), your code looks good, though it is generally easier to use `dup2()` instead of `close()` plus `dup()` as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Same code with **dup2**: (I let you make your m_exec function)

```
int      m_pipe(char *cmd1, char *cmd2)
{
  int    fd[2];

  if (pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
      perror("Pipe failed ");
      return (-1);
    }
  if (fork() == 0)
    {
      /*Child process*/
      dup2(fd[0], 0);
      close(fd[1]);
      m_exec(cmd2);
    }
  else
    {
      /*Parent process*/
      dup2(fd[1], 1);
      close(fd[0]);
      m_exec(cmd1);
    }
  return (0);
}

int    main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(argc != 3)
    {
      write(2, "Usage ./a.out cmd1 cmd2\n", strlen("Usage ./a.out cmd1 cmd2\n"));
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  if (m_pipe(argv[1], argv[2]) == -1)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```